# Is w*-sequential closure idempotent?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a closed subspace of $X^{**}$. Consider $K(F)$ to be linear subspace of $X^{**}$ consisting of weak*-limits of w*-convergent sequences from $F$. Is it true that

$$K(K(F)) = K(F)? $$

I couldn't find any immediate counterexamples to this claim.

Comment: Why are you considering $F \subset X^{**}$ and not $F \subset X^{*}$? Typically, weak* convergence would be defined on the dual space of $X$, so is there a particular reason that you consider it on $X^{**}$?

I mean, you could otherwise replace $X$ by $Y := X^*$ and all your statements would be down "one level", requiring one star less everywhere, i.e. $F \subset Y^{*}$, $K(F) \subset Y^{*}$..

Comment: For just topological spaces, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458364/why-is-the-sequential-closure-not-sequentially-closed ...

Comment: also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799452/taking-two-times-the-sequential-closure-of-the-set-of-continuous-functions-in-th

Comment: So the hint would be: take a good counterexample in toplogical spaces, and convert it to a counterexample for weak* topology in some Banach space.

Comment: @GEdgar, this need not be easy as we deal with linear subspaces, rather than arbitrary sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative as proved by Mazurkiewicz:

S. Mazurkiewicz, [Sur la dérivée faible d'un ensemble de fonctionnelles linéaires](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm2/sm219.pdf), Studia Math. 2 (1930), 68–71.